# large curly braces with long vertical condtional line

Tags: cases, vertical, large-symbols

I am trying to write a math equation with multiple cases in the condition : here is the code I have :

```
    \begin{equation*} 
\begin{aligned}
q(\mathcal A | \mathcal C ) =
\begin{cases}
 (t, CI_{1-\alpha})\mid \exists g \in \mathbb{R} \land \land(g \;\text {is a consistent estimator for}\;  \mathcal  C)\\
& \land (g \; \text {satisfies} \; \mathcal  C)\land( CI_{1-\alpha}  \text {is the} (1-\alpha)\% \text {confidence interval} )\\
   \end{cases} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

I want tho have a large curly braces with long vertical condition line as follows :
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you use a `\left\{ ... \middle\vert ... \right]}` construct, along with an `aligned` environment between `\middle\vert` and `\right\}`. And, be sure to insert enough whitespace -- specifically, `\thinspace` (`\,`) with the curly braces and `\thickspace` (`\;`) with the vertical bar -- around the tall delimiters.

[image]

You may ask, where does the advice to use `\thinspace` and `\thickspace` come from? Knuth recommends this on page 174 in Chapter 18, "Fine points of mathematics typing", in the TeXbook. And if it's good enough for Knuth ...

Of course, do be sure to keep an eye on whether this construct fits within the text block. If necessary, apply abbreviations, e.g., by replacing `confidence interval` with `conf.\ int.`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'equation*' and 'aligned' env.'s and '\text' macro
\usepackage{amssymb} % for '\mathcal' directive

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*} 
q(\,\mathcal{A} \mid \mathcal{C} \,) = % use '\mid', not '|'
\left\{ \,
  (t, \mathrm{CI}_{1-\alpha})
\; \middle\vert \;
  \begin{aligned}
    &\exists\, g \in \mathbb{R} \\
    &\land(\text{$g$ is a consistent estimator for $\mathcal {C}$})\\
    &\land (\text{$g$ satisfies $\mathcal{C}$}) \\
    &\land(\text{$\mathrm{CI}_{1-\alpha}$ is the $(1-\alpha)$ confidence interval} )
  \end{aligned}
\, \right\}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked great. Thanks a lot.